# MenuBar issue QT 4.7.4 on MAC OS LION

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, menubar

I'm new to QT programming. I want to create a simple menubar with two menus , and several actions (3 actions for FILE menu and one action for VIEW menu).I have createMenus() method where i create those menus and actions then I add created menus to menubar ,but when i run the app , it's not showing this menubar , and i dont know why. Can anyone tell what the problem is ?

Source code of MainWindow.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QAction>
#include "MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow() {

        // Creeam fereastra principala
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    setCentralWidget(window);

    // Creeam eticheta unde vom afisa titlul item-ului selectat
    // Implicit va avea un titlu predefinit
   infoLabel = new QLabel("Selectati un item va rog ");

    createActions();
    createMenus();

    // Creeam un layout pentru pozitionarea etichetei
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(infoLabel);
    window->setLayout(layout);

    setWindowTitle("GUI");
    setMinimumSize(300, 300);
    resize(480,320);
}

void MainWindow::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event) {

    QMenu menu(this);
    menu.addAction(newAction);
    menu.addAction(openAction);
    menu.addAction(closeAction);
    menu.addAction(preferencesAction);
    menu.exec(event->globalPos());
}

void MainWindow::new_() {

    infoLabel->setText("A fost selectat : NEW");
}

void MainWindow::open() {

     infoLabel->setText("A fost selectat : OPEN");
}

void MainWindow::close() {

}

void MainWindow::preferences() {

     infoLabel->setText("A fost selectat : PREFERENCES");
}


void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    newAction = new QAction("New", this);
    connect(newAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(new_()));

    openAction = new QAction("Open", this);
    connect(openAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(open()));

    closeAction = new QAction("Close", this);
    connect(closeAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));

    preferencesAction = new QAction("Preferences", this);
    connect(preferencesAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(preferences()));
}

void MainWindow::createMenus()
{
    // Creeaza sectiunea File
    fileMenu = new QMenu ("File");

    // Adauga actiunile new,open si close la sectiunea File
    fileMenu->addAction(newAction);
    fileMenu->addAction(openAction);
    fileMenu->addAction(closeAction);


    //  Creeaza sectiunea View
     viewMenu = new QMenu ("View");

    //Adauga actiunea preferences la sectiunea View
    viewMenu->addAction(preferencesAction);

    menuBar()->addMenu(fileMenu);
    menuBar()->addMenu(viewMenu);
}
```

Comment: Just tried your code with Qt 4.5.2 on Linux and it worked fine. I can't see anything wrong with it. Which version of Qt are you using and which platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using QT 4.7.4 on MAC OS LION

Comment: Do you get a menu if you do `QMenuBar *menuBar = new QMenuBar(0);` and then install this on the main window with `setMenuBar(menuBar)`? I only mention it as the [docs for QMainWindow](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) mention this should have an effect on Mac. I know that's not what you want to do of course, just curious if it has an effect.

Comment: Troubadour, please post your comment as answer, so it may be accepted

Comment: could you upload the mainwindow.cpp, mainwindow.h and main.cpp please? im having the same problem but i dont uderstand how u answer it :S
when i run it, its shows just the window but not the menu bar :S

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> **SOLVED** : Must create a parent-less menu bar this way:

```
QMenuBar *menuBar = new QMenuBar(0);
```

> Then add menus and actions.