# QMenuBar and QMenu doesn't show in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmenu, qmenubar

I'm using **Qt 4.7.4** on **Mac OS X 10.7.4**, and **I'm trying to add a `QMenuBar` and a `QMenu`** to my application without success.

When looking for examples, I found the [Basic Layouts](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/layouts-basiclayouts.html) and the screenshot of the interface on Windows displays the **File** menu, which is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

**However**, running this example on Mac OS X  doesn't show the *File* menu inside the application window:

[image]

and it also doesn't show in the top Mac OS X bar:

[image]

It seems that this is either a bug of Qt 4.7.4 on Mac OS X, or we are required to do some tweaks on the source code to make it work on Mac.

**How can I fix this problem?**

I've [found similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972721/menubar-issue-qt-4-7-4-on-mac-os-lion) posts on Stack Overflow but none helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem in the code, nor in Qt. The example you cite only creates an `Exit` action in the menu. On OS X, such actions belong in the application menu, not in the File menu. Your application is called `qt_menu`, and that's how the application menu is called, and that's where you will find the `Quit` action -- Qt has correctly renamed it to agree with Apple's HIG. On Windows, it'd be customary to call it Exit, on a Mac it's bad style. Qt's behavior is correct, and I can reproduce it.

Add other actions to the file menu, or simply rename the one action from `Exit` to something else.

Note that Qt doesn't move actions directly based on their name. Qt guesses the action *roles* based on their name. You should override such guesses and set action roles explicitly using `QAction::setMenuRole()`. Those roles then get interpreted appropriately on various platforms.